# Find a WPF element inside DataTemplate in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, element, datatemplate

Here is my XAML

```
<ItemsControl Name="itmCntrl" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Name="stk">
                <StackPanel Margin="5,2,0,0">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,10,10,5" Height="Auto">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbNI" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Text="{Binding NUMINDEX}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Text="{Binding QUESTION}"/>                                              
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,5,10,5" Height="Auto">
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoA" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=A}"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="tbA" Text="{Binding A}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="1000"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoB" Margin="0,0,0,0" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=B}"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="tbB" Text="{Binding B}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="1000"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoC" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=C}"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="tbC" Text="{Binding C}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="1000"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdoD" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=D}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="tbD" Text="{Binding D}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What I want to do when click on SubmitButton is (Code Behind):

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{                
    if(rdoA.IsChecked == true)
    {
        Add(tbNI.Text,'A')
    }
    else if(rdoB.IsChecked == true)
    {
        Add(tbNI.Text,'B')
    }
    else if(rdoC.IsChecked == true)
    {
        Add(tbNI.Text,'C')
    }
    else if(rdoD.IsChecked == true)
    {
        Add(tbNI.Text,'D')
    }
}
```

So How can I access the textbox and radiobutton in DataTemplate? I know that I should use VisualTreeHelper but I'm still new and can't access it. Any one have solution for this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13168275/815938) may help you.

Comment: the right way is adding to model a boolean property for each `RadioButton` value and bind them to `RadioButton`'s `IsChecked` propertry. or more simple, one enum property, and instead four `RadioButton` place a `ListBox`with four Items, and Bind the `SelectedIndex` to model.

Comment: So I should add 4 rdo + Textblock to Listbox instead of WrapPanel ? Can U gimme some code plz :( @lomed